# JavaScript function is only working for the first element with a class name, not all elements with that class

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple forms on one page with same structure.

They all have a file input field that has 'onchange' event, which removes the 'disabled' attribute from my submit button when a file is chosen.

The problem is, my function only works for the first element with that class name. How can I make it work for every item with that class?

index.php:

```
<form class="form">
    <input type="file" name="image" onchange="unlock();">
    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Image title"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Add image" class="submit" disabled/>
</form>

<form class="form">
    <input type="file" name="image" onchange="unlock();">
    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Image title"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Add image" class="submit" disabled/>
</form>
```

scripts.js:

```
function unlock() {
    document.querySelector('.submit').removeAttribute("disabled");
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: OP the script as written won't work *at all*; `.getElementsByClassName()` returns a node list, not an element. You have to explicitly iterate over the list to manipulate the elements.

Comment: I edited my question, had a bit wrong script there. I have querySelector in what case only first element with class submit works properly..

Comment: `querySelector` has the explicit purpose of returning only the first matched element. (You should go and _read up_ on what the methods you use actually do, instead of assuming something, and then being surprised if it behaves differently.) You want querySelectorAll instead, and then as already mentioned, you need to loop over the items in the resulting list.

Comment: Look it up! `querySelector` vs `querySelectorAll`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use eventListener
2. address relatively using selectors
3. make it a habit to never call anything submit in a form

```js
document.querySelectorAll("[name=image]").forEach(
    ele => ele.addEventListener("change",
      (e) => e.target.closest(".form").querySelector(".sub").disabled = false
    )      
);
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <input type="file" name="image">
  <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Image title" />
  <input type="submit" value="Add image" class="sub" disabled/>
</form>

<form class="form">
  <input type="file" name="image">
  <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Image title" />
  <input type="submit" value="Add image" class="sub" disabled/>
</form>
```

More compatible version

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll("[name=image]")].forEach(function(ele) {
  ele.addEventListener("change",
    function(e) {
      e.target.parentNode.querySelector(".sub").disabled = false;
    })
});
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <input type="file" name="image">
  <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Image title" />
  <input type="submit" value="Add image" class="sub" disabled/>
</form>

<form class="form">
  <input type="file" name="image">
  <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Image title" />
  <input type="submit" value="Add image" class="sub" disabled/>
</form>
```

Comment: If Browser compatibility is a matter of case for you use "function" instead of "=>" (arrow function) e.g.:
document.querySelectorAll("[name=image]").forEach(function(ele) { 
    ele.addEventListener("change",function() {
        e.target.closest(".form").querySelector(".sub").disabled = false
    });
});

Comment: @prestock querySelectorAll().forEach and closest are also problematic. See second example

Answer (score 0):

Give ID's to all submit buttons and pass the respective ID's in unlock() function.

This removes the disabled from the submit

```js
function unlock(form_id) {
  document.getElementById(form_id).removeAttribute("disabled");
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <input type="file" name="image" onchange="unlock('form1');">
  <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Image title" />
  <input type="submit" id="form1" value="Add image" class="submit" disabled/>
</form>

<form class="form">
  <input type="file" name="image" onchange="unlock('form2');">
  <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Image title" />
  <input type="submit" id="form2" value="Add image" class="submit" disabled/>
</form>
```

Comment: Actually, it would not work if the image title was also disabled. So removing disabled from the form, only removes it from the submit button. It is not very obvious and I would personally not do it like that.